# Do there exist non-empty sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A\times B \subseteq A$?

Tags: set-theory

In ZFC, can such sets exist? Obviously, if they exist, then $A$ must be infinite, but that's about all I've been able to deduce.

Comment: If for all $a \in A$ and $b,c,d \in B$, then are you suggesting that having $(a,b)$ and $((a,b),c)$ and  $(((a,b),c),d)$ etc. all being elements of $A$ would be possible?  How about $B=\mathbb N$ and $A$ finite sequences of natural numbers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start with any set $X$, then define $A_0=X$,and $A_{n+1}=A_n\cup (A_n\times A_n)$. Finally, let $A$ be the union $\bigcup\{A_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$.

Now we have that $A\times A\subseteq A$. To see that, note that if $a,b\in A$, then there is some $n$ such that $a,b\in A_n$, so $(a,b)\in A_n\times A_n\subset A_{n+1}\subset A$.

Comment: +1. My edit was to ensure that it reached the maximum of obviousness.